# Is it possible to use Gephi-0.8.2 with Neo4j-2.1.8?

Tags: neo4j, gephi

What I've read about Gephi-0.8.2 is that I should use Neo4j-2.1.3, but I also noticed that the server is no longer available for download.

Using Gephi-0.8.2 with Neo4j-2.1.8, I'm trying to load a graph of a database. I do it using the Import Traversal option and I get the following exception captured in the log file of Gephi,

```
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Found same position 600 for    
both Menu/File/org-gephi-desktop-importer-ImportDB.instance and 
Menu/File/org-gephi-desktop-neo4j-Neo4jMenuAction.instance
WARNING     [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateproviders.AutoupdateCatalogFactory]:  
  Services/AutoupdateType/org_gephi_branding_update_center.instance:  
  url_key attribute deprecated in favor of url
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateproviders.AutoupdateCatalogFactory]:  
Services/AutoupdateType/org_gephi_branding_update_center_1.instance:  
url_key attribute deprecated in favor of url
WARNING [org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager]: use of system property 
netbeans.user has been obsoleted in favor of InstalledFileLocator/Places
at org.neo4j.kernel.info.SystemDiagnostics$7.dump 
(SystemDiagnostics.java:239)
SEVERE [global]
org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.getCurrentTransaction(PersistenceManager.java:297)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.assertInTransaction(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:67)
at org.neo4j.tooling.GlobalGraphOperations.assertInTransaction(GlobalGraphOperations.java:236)
at org.neo4j.tooling.GlobalGraphOperations.getAllRelationshipTypes(GlobalGraphOperations.java:123)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.getRelationshipTypes(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:1074)
at org.gephi.desktop.neo4j.ui.util.Neo4jUtils.relationshipTypeNames(Neo4jUtils.java:59)
at org.gephi.desktop.neo4j.ui.TraversalImportPanel.initComponents(TraversalImportPanel.java:191)
at org.gephi.desktop.neo4j.ui.TraversalImportPanel.<init>(TraversalImportPanel.java:55)
at org.gephi.desktop.neo4j.Neo4jMenuAction$TraversalImportMenuAction.showTraversalDialog(Neo4jMenuAction.java:379)
at org.gephi.desktop.neo4j.Neo4jMenuAction$TraversalImportMenuAction.actionPerformed(Neo4jMenuAction.java:334)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown  
    Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown  
    Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    [catch] at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:158)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Does exist any way to work properly in this environment? My system is windows 8.1 pro.

All the best,

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does the import graphdb work?

Comment: Yes, it is a possibility but I should need the driver of Neo4j. Thanks, let me try it.

Answer (score 1):

At the end I decided for Gephi 0.9. The problem is that this version of the app does not come with the driver for Neo4j server so I had to create it and adapt the app for this new driver.

Here are the changes I did,

1) **Module DBDrivers.-**

I created the driver for Neo4j server as follows,

```
package org.gephi.io.database.drivers;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Jose Alvarez de Lara
 */
public class Neo4jDriver implements SQLDriver {

    public Neo4jDriver() {
        try {
            // load the Neo4j-JDBC driver using the current class loader
            Class.forName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Neo4jDriver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection(String connectionUrl, String username, String passwd) throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPrefix() {
        return "neo4j";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Neo4j";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Neo4jDriver) {
            return ((Neo4jDriver) obj).getPrefix().equals(getPrefix());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getPrefix().hashCode();
    }

}
```

2) **Module ImportPluginUI.-**

I did some changes in the code of the EdgeListPanel.java class file witch are as follow,

In the constructor I added the extensión for Neo4j,

```
public EdgeListPanel() {
    databaseManager = new EdgeListDatabaseManager();
    initComponents();

    driverComboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
            initDriverType((SQLDriver) ie.getItem());
        }
    });

    browseButton.setVisible(false);
    browseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            String lastPath = NbPreferences.forModule(EdgeListPanel.class).get(LAST_PATH, "");
            final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(lastPath);
            chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            chooser.setDialogTitle(NbBundle.getMessage(EdgeListPanel.class, "EdgeListPanel.sqliteFileChooser.title"));
            DialogFileFilter dialogFileFilter = new DialogFileFilter(NbBundle.getMessage(EdgeListPanel.class, "EdgeListPanel.sqliteFileChooser.filefilter"));
            dialogFileFilter.addExtension("sqlite");

            dialogFileFilter.addExtension("neo4j"); //add extensión for neo4j

            dialogFileFilter.addExtension("db");
            chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(dialogFileFilter);

            int returnFile = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
            if (returnFile != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                return;
            }
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            hostTextField.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());

            //Save last path
            NbPreferences.forModule(EdgeListPanel.class).put(LAST_PATH, file.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath());
        }
    });
}
```

In initDriverType() method I enabled the panel for Neo4j,

```
private void initDriverType(final SQLDriver driver) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (driver != null && driver.getPrefix().equals("sqlite")) {
                hostLabel.setText(NbBundle.getMessage(EdgeListPanel.class, "EdgeListPanel.fileLabel.text"));
                portTextField.setEnabled(false);
                portLabel.setEnabled(false);
                dbLabel.setEnabled(false);
                dbTextField.setEnabled(false);
                userLabel.setEnabled(false);
                userTextField.setEnabled(false);
                pwdLabel.setEnabled(false);
                pwdTextField.setEnabled(false);
                pwdTextField.setText("");
                userTextField.setText("");
                dbTextField.setText("");
                portTextField.setText("");
                browseButton.setVisible(true);


            } else if (driver != null && driver.getPrefix().equals("neo4j")) {
                hostLabel.setText(NbBundle.getMessage(EdgeListPanel.class, "EdgeListPanel.hostLabel.text"));
                portTextField.setEnabled(true);
                portLabel.setEnabled(true);
                dbLabel.setEnabled(false);
                dbTextField.setEnabled(false);
                userLabel.setEnabled(false);
                userTextField.setEnabled(false);
                pwdLabel.setEnabled(false);
                pwdTextField.setEnabled(false);
                pwdTextField.setText("");
                userTextField.setText("");
                dbTextField.setText("");
                browseButton.setVisible(false);


            } else {
                hostLabel.setText(NbBundle.getMessage(EdgeListPanel.class, "EdgeListPanel.hostLabel.text"));
                portTextField.setEnabled(true);
                portLabel.setEnabled(true);
                dbLabel.setEnabled(true);
                dbTextField.setEnabled(true);
                userLabel.setEnabled(true);
                userTextField.setEnabled(true);
                pwdLabel.setEnabled(true);
                pwdTextField.setEnabled(true);
                browseButton.setVisible(false);
            }
            group.validateAll();
        }
    });
}
```

The following method is a more general method then the old one isSqlite() because it let me pass any prefix I need. In this case they should be “sqlite” and “neo4j”

```
private static boolean isValidDriverPrefix(EdgeListPanel panel, String prefix) {
    if (panel.databaseManager.getEdgeListDatabases().size() > 0) {
        if (panel.databaseManager.getEdgeListDatabases().get(0).getSQLDriver().getPrefix().equals(prefix)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } else if (panel.getSelectedSQLDriver().getPrefix().equals(prefix)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And I used it in the following inner classes of this one,

```
private static class HostOrFileValidator implements Validator<String> {

    private EdgeListPanel panel;

    public HostOrFileValidator(EdgeListPanel panel) {
        this.panel = panel;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validate(Problems problems, String compName, String model) {
        if (isValidDriverPrefix(panel, "sqlite")) {
            return Validators.FILE_MUST_BE_FILE.validate(problems, compName, model);
        } else {
            return Validators.REQUIRE_NON_EMPTY_STRING.validate(problems, compName, model);
        }
    }
}

private static class NotEmptyValidator implements Validator<String> {

    private EdgeListPanel panel;

    public NotEmptyValidator(EdgeListPanel panel) {
        this.panel = panel;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validate(Problems problems, String compName, String model) {
        if (isValidDriverPrefix(panel, "sqlite") || isValidDriverPrefix(panel, "neo4j")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return Validators.REQUIRE_NON_EMPTY_STRING.validate(problems, compName, model);
        }
    }
}

private static class PortValidator implements Validator<String> {

    private EdgeListPanel panel;

    public PortValidator(EdgeListPanel panel) {
        this.panel = panel;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validate(Problems problems, String compName, String model) {
        if (isValidDriverPrefix(panel, "sqlite")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return Validators.REQUIRE_NON_EMPTY_STRING.validate(problems, compName, model)
                    && Validators.REQUIRE_VALID_INTEGER.validate(problems, compName, model)
                    && Validators.numberRange(1, 65535).validate(problems, compName, model);
        }
    }
}
```

3) **Module ImportPlugin.-**

In this module I had to adapt the class file ImporterEdgeList.java changing the methods getNodes() and getEdges() because they threw a NullPointerException while achieving a Neo4j graph database. It was really simple,

```
private void getNodes(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

    //Factory
    ElementDraftFactory factory = container.factory();

    //Properties
    PropertiesAssociations properties = database.getPropertiesAssociations();

    Statement s = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        rs = s.executeQuery(database.getNodeQuery());
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        report.logIssue(new Issue("Failed to execute Node query", Issue.Level.SEVERE, ex));
        return;
    }

    findNodeAttributesColumns(rs);
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnsCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    int count = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        String id = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < columnsCount; i++) {
            String columnName = metaData.getColumnLabel(i + 1);
            NodeProperties p = properties.getNodeProperty(columnName);

            if (p != null) { //Here p could be null

                if (p.equals(NodeProperties.ID)) {
                    String ide = rs.getString(i + 1);
                    if (ide != null) {
                        id = ide;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        NodeDraft node;
        if (id != null) {
            node = factory.newNodeDraft(id);
        } else {
            node = factory.newNodeDraft();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < columnsCount; i++) {
            String columnName = metaData.getColumnLabel(i + 1);
            NodeProperties p = properties.getNodeProperty(columnName);
            if (p != null) {
                injectNodeProperty(p, rs, i + 1, node);
            } else {
                //Inject node attributes
                ColumnDraft col = container.getNodeColumn(columnName);
                injectElementAttribute(rs, i + 1, col, node);
            }
        }
        // injectTimeIntervalProperty(node);
        container.addNode(node);
        ++count;
    }
    rs.close();
    s.close();

}

private void getEdges(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

    //Factory
    ElementDraftFactory factory = container.factory();

    //Properties
    PropertiesAssociations properties = database.getPropertiesAssociations();

    Statement s = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        rs = s.executeQuery(database.getEdgeQuery());
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        report.logIssue(new Issue("Failed to execute Edge query", Issue.Level.SEVERE, ex));
        return;
    }
    findEdgeAttributesColumns(rs);
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnsCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    int count = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        String id = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < columnsCount; i++) {
            String columnName = metaData.getColumnLabel(i + 1);
            EdgeProperties p = properties.getEdgeProperty(columnName);

            if (p != null) { //Here p could be null

                if (p.equals(EdgeProperties.ID)) {
                    String ide = rs.getString(i + 1);
                    if (ide != null) {
                        id = ide;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        EdgeDraft edge;
        if (id != null) {
            edge = factory.newEdgeDraft(id);
        } else {
            edge = factory.newEdgeDraft();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < columnsCount; i++) {
            String columnName = metaData.getColumnLabel(i + 1);
            EdgeProperties p = properties.getEdgeProperty(columnName);
            if (p != null) {
                injectEdgeProperty(p, rs, i + 1, edge);
            } else {
                //Inject edge attributes
                ColumnDraft col = container.getEdgeColumn(columnName);
                injectElementAttribute(rs, i + 1, col, edge);
            }
        }
        // injectTimeIntervalProperty(edge);
        container.addEdge(edge);
        ++count;
    }
    rs.close();
    s.close();
}
```

And that was all.

Gephi 0.9 after these changes was tested against Neo4j 2.1.8 movies database and the same example database of Neo4j 2.3.0-M01 when no auth is required.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Here's https://gephi.wordpress.com/tag/database/ a blog post where you can find all about the plug-in of Neo4j for Gephi-0.8.2. It is a good job, a really good job

Comment: well, it does obviously not restore the plugin functionality, but does the job if there is no other option. Actually quite easy to apply. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To build Gephi-0.9 you better use the latest NetBeans IDE, and from https://github.com/gephi/gephi download the app and the source code.

Open the source code witch is a maven project into NetBeans IDE and, if you prefer to, extract the corresponding modules to make the changes as a an independent maven projects.

Once you are done copy the contents of the …\target\nbm\netbeans\gephi folder into the corresponding …\gephi\gephi folders of Gephi-0.9 app and then you are ready to go.

Here is the pom.xml file of the DBDrivers module,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>gephi-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.gephi</groupId>
    <version>0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../..</relativePath>
</parent>

<groupId>org.gephi</groupId>
<artifactId>db-drivers</artifactId>
<version>0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>nbm</packaging>

<name>DBDrivers</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1301.101</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.teradata</groupId>
        <artifactId>teradata-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>14.00.00.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.teradata</groupId>
        <artifactId>teradata-config</artifactId>
        <version>14.00.00.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-openide-util-lookup</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <publicPackages>
                     <publicPackage>org.gephi.io.database.drivers</publicPackage>
                </publicPackages>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```